# How can i remove a Property from a react component on router path change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-component

I am trying to Have a navbar that is transparent on the landing page but i don't want it to be transparent when I am on other pages. is there a way to do that or should i try another method?

```
render() {
return (
  <>
    {
      Route.path === '/' ? <Header transparent={this.state.transparent} /> : <Header />
    }

    <Switch>
      <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
      <Route path='/aboutus' component={AboutUs} />
      <Route path='/shop' component={Shop} />
    </Switch>
    <Footer />
  </>
);
```

}

I want to do something like this or a way to remove the transparent property when the path is different

Here is the state

```
constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  transparent: true,
}
this.listener = null}
```

and the rest of the code is

```
componentDidMount() {
this.listener = document.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  let scrolled = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop;
  if (scrolled >= 150) {
    if (this.state.transparent !== false) {
      this.setState({ transparent: false});
    }
  } else {
    if (this.state.transparent !== true) {
      this.setState({ transparent: true});
    }
  }
});
```

}

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
document.removeEventListener("scroll", this.listener);
```

}

what can i do here guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this a few ways. The easiest is probably to use the [useRouteMatch](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useroutematch) hook in your `Header` component to test for the route you want the header to behave differently on.

```
const Header = () => {
  const match = useRouteMatch({
    pathname: '/',
    exact: true
  });

  return (
    ... JSX ... apply transparent logic on match
  );
}
```

App

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/aboutus' component={AboutUs} />
        <Route path='/shop' component={Shop} />
        <Route path='/' component={Home} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
}
```

Alternatively, if `Header` isn't a function component you either render directly on a `Route`, or decorate with the [withRouter](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component, and check the `location` prop. In `Header` in the `render` lifecycle method check `this.props.location.pathname`.

```
render() {
  const { location } = this.props;
  const isTransparent = location.pathname === "/";

  return (
    ... JSX ... apply transparent logic
  );
}
```

Comment: The Header is a function component but i didn't understand the part you said apply transparent logic on match?

Comment: @Nathnael In your code snippet you were passing a `transparent` prop, i.e. `<Header transparent={this.state.transparent} />`, but my proposed solution computes this internally. I'm just saying to apply the existing logic against the new source of a "transparent" value.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i was able to make it but not exactly as you said. i wasn't able to take the transparent logic inside the component did mount and component did update and put it in the  header component. but i added the condition is exact on top of the value of the transparent logic to make it work. your method might've been better and i will try to make it work your way.

Answer (score 0):

To determine current path use `useLocation().pathname` hook. For this you need react-router-dom of version 6.x (dont know if works even on 5.x) and then code should look like:

```
const pathname = useLocation().pathname
render(
...
{
pathname === '/' ? a : b
}
...
)
```